# Resident memory greater than --max-old-space-size threshold?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, memory-management, v8

I'm running a dockerised node.js application on my server, using the `--max-old-space-size` option to limit the applications heap size. The following output is given by htop:

```
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
10158 root       20   0  4284   720   644 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 sh -c node --max-old-space-size=512 ./dist/www.js
10159 root       20   0 1841M  929M 29592 S  0.0  3.0  1h31:16 node --max-old-space-size=512 ./dist/www.js
10160 root       20   0 1841M  929M 29592 S  0.0  3.0  0:00.00 node --max-old-space-size=512 ./dist/www.js
10161 root       20   0 1841M  929M 29592 S  0.0  3.0  7:27.13 node --max-old-space-size=512 ./dist/www.js
10162 root       20   0 1841M  929M 29592 S  0.0  3.0  7:26.96 node --max-old-space-size=512 ./dist/www.js
10163 root       20   0 1841M  929M 29592 S  0.0  3.0  7:26.99 node --max-old-space-size=512 ./dist/www.js
10164 root       20   0 1841M  929M 29592 S  0.0  3.0  7:26.64 node --max-old-space-size=512 ./dist/www.js
```

You can see my applications resident memory (929M) is way above my `max-old-space-size` value (512MB) so why is this being seen? Shouldn't the application have aborted by this point?

**System Info**

```
Docker version: 19.03.5
node image version: 11.13.0

uname -v
#31~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 17 10:48:34 UTC 2020
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

V8 developer here. The `--max-old-space-size` flag does not directly control the overall process' memory consumption; it puts a limit on one part (the biggest part) of V8's managed (i.e. garbage-collected) heap, which is the chunk of memory where all the JavaScript objects are put. Aside from this "old space", V8 also has a (much smaller) "new space"; and besides V8's managed heap, there are a bunch of other consumers of memory in the process: for example, within V8, parser and compiler use memory outside the managed heap; and then aside from V8, Node puts a bunch of things in memory too. Depending on what exactly the embedder (i.e. Node) and the executing code do, large strings and ArrayBuffers can also live outside of the managed heap.

In short, `--max-old-space-size` gives you *one* knob to affect how much memory will be used, but the limit you set there is not a limit for the process' overall memory consumption. (For comparison, in Chrome, typically about a third of a renderer process' memory is V8's managed heap, though depending on what websites do there are significant outliers in both directions. I don't know typical numbers for Node.)

Answer (score -1):

The RES that you can see on the `top` is the non-swapped region of the virtual memory of a linux process (see `man top` for more details). Here is short snipped of the explanation

```
22. RES  --  Resident Memory Size (KiB)
     A subset of the virtual address space (VIRT) representing the non-swapped 
physical memory a task is currently using.  It is also the sum of the 
RSan, RSfd and RSsh fields.

     It  can  include private anonymous pages, private pages mapped to files 
(including program images and shared libraries) plus shared anonymous pages.  
All such memory is backed by the swap file represented separately under SWAP.
```

The output of `top` should not be confused with the `node.js` memory model elements, since this output is giving the kernel view of the process, while internal memory organizations (like in this case of `node.js`) are not visible.

If you want to get more details on the structure (the memory map) of the process, you can use `pmap -x <PID>` and you will see which memory segments are currently in the RES, however this segments are also not to be confused with the `node.js` segments (although, some of them can be directly mapped to the `node.js` segments).

`node.js` memory map, which is the subset of the whole process memory allocated, is called `Resident Set` and should not be confused with the `Resident Memory Size` - `RES`. In fact, the `Resident Set` of `node.js` is more closer to the value that you can see in `VIRT`. The difference between `VIRT` and the `Resident Set` will be attributed to the unix shared libraries (not to be confused with `node.js` modules) that are loaded by the `node.js`, files that the process had opened, etc.).

The `Resident Set` is further divided in the `Code Segment`, `Stack Segment` and the `Heap Segment`. The `Code Segment`, as the name suggests, contains the executable code. The `Stack Segment` contains the stack informations of the currently running threads in the process. This [blog](https://deepu.tech/memory-management-in-v8/) provides good overview of the memory organization.

What remains from all of this is the `Heap Segment`. And here is where the configuration parameter `max-old-space-size` has a role to play. The heap of `node.js` follows memory model that is very similar to Java garbage collection memory model. The parameter is telling the process how much objects are allowed to survive consecutive garbage collection cycles. However, this doesn't mean that this objects are un-swappable, with other words, it's not given that all of the 512MB that are set will reside in `RES`. This is a subsegment of the `Heap`. The `Old Space` is a sub-segment of the `Heap`.

So, what you read in `RES` had no direct link to the `Old Space Sub-Segment` of the `Heap Segment`. In applications where there is huge garbage left from the short leaving applications contexts (variable is the context that are not retained by the application), the `Old Generation` will be very small, however the `RES` will grow rapidly and the setting will not help you to manage the memory of the process.

Comment: Some of these details are incorrect. "Resident set" and "resident memory" are synonyms; "VIRT" is not attributed to libraries, it's reserved address space which is quite unrelated to actual memory usage (except that it's an upper bound). The JavaScript heap is always part of RES, and there is no scenario where short-lived objects make the overall heap grow massively (because new-space is size-limited and frequently collected; if anything grows then it's old-space, which _is_ controlled by the flag in question).

Comment: You are confusing the `RES` from unix perspective that `top` is providing and the `Resident Set` from `node.js`. `node.js` is a process in linux and `RES` is the measurement of how much of the process memory is in the physical memory.

Comment: `man top` calls "RES" the "Resident Memory Size", `man htop` (which the OP uses) calls it "Resident Set Size". It's the same thing. You may want to use a different term for your description of different things in the memory of a process. -- The deepu.tech blog post you linked contains a number of inaccuracies (some of it is outdated [e.g. there is no cell space any more], some stuff is missing [e.g. the Unix "Heap" is more than the V8 managed heap], and some statements plain wrong [e.g. strings are never on the stack]).

Comment: `top` is oblivious that the process is `node.js`.  As`top` is a utility from the operating system and you need to read it's output from the perspective of the operating system. If you want to read it from `node.js` perspective, you will end up with wrong conclusions, like `RES` of linux is same as `Resident Set` of node.js.

Comment: Of course `top` treats all processes the same. There is no Node-specific definition of "Resident Set", it's the same for all processes: physical memory used. Of course, if we want to know more about what exactly Node uses the memory for, then `top` can't help us.

Comment: And the question is all about how to use the output of `top` to determine the `node.js` heap size, so I think I deserve for however placed the down vote to remove it.